# jquery hide/show list elements from ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I want to make a script which handles "show more/less" of the elements of an list. I found this script:

HTML

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
    <li>Eleven</li>
    <li>Twelve</li>
</ul>
<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

CSS

```
#myList li{ display:none;
}
#loadMore {
    color:green;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#loadMore:hover {
    color:black;
}
#showLess {
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#showLess:hover {
    color:black;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
        if(x<=3){$('#showLess').hide();}
    });
    $('#showLess').click(function () {
        x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
        $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6FzSb/1550/

And now im wondering how javascript line 6 and 10 is working and how I can hide the showmore if all entries are shown and how to hide showless if only 3 entries left as shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this way

```
var visible = 3;
$("#myList li:lt(" + visible + ")").show();
$("#loadMore").click(function() {
    $("#showLess").show();
    visible = $("#myList li:visible").length + 3;
    $("#myList li:lt(" + visible + ")").show();
    if (visible == $("#myList li").length)
        $(this).hide();
});
$("#showLess").click(function() {
    $("#loadMore").show();
    visible = $("#myList li:visible").length - 3;
    $("#myList li:gt(" + (visible - 1) + ")").hide();
    if (3 == $("#myList li:visible").length)
        $(this).hide();

});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6FzSb/1562/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about

```
$('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
```

then google for 'jquery selector lt'.

As to how to show/hide show more/less links: you have all the hints in your code -- you know how to compute the list size (..size()), how to hide and show DOM elements (..hide() and ..show()) so now have a couple of if blocks which hide the 'show less' on load and hide 'show more' in the click handler.

Comment: Nonono, i mean `x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;` and `x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;` thats what i dont understand/know what it does...

Comment: @MartinFischer google for 'ternary operator'. The logic in first one is, for example: 'if x is less than 5 entries before the end evaluate to x+5 else evaluate to size_li'

Comment: Thank you, that was my question

Answer (score 1):

Check this updated code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
size_li = $("#myList li").size();
x=3;
$('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
 $('#showLess').hide();
$('#loadMore').click(function () {
    x= (x+5 <= size_li) ? x+5 : size_li;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();

    if(size_li == x){
        $(this).hide();
    }else{
        $('#showLess').show();
    }
});
$('#showLess').click(function () {
    x=(x-5<0) ? 3 : x-5;
    $('#myList li').not(':lt('+x+')').hide();        
    if(x <= 3){
        $('#showLess').hide();
    }else{
       $('#loadMore').show(); 
    }
});
```

});

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6FzSb/1558/)